# Not being able to convert list or string into dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Info needed: This is in Python 3.4.1

I'm having problems trying to figure out how an object that i get from telnet works. I use this code:

```
def EventHandler(sender, event):
    print("Printing server response: " + str(event.parsed)) #This is the server text
    print(type(event.parsed)) #I try to check what it's, seems a list
    TryingToFix = str(event.parsed)[1:-1] #I try to make it a string...
    dict(TryingToFix) #...just to later try to make it a dict
    print(TryingToFix) #this never works
```

And the result is:

```
Printing server response: [{'targetmode': '2', 'invokername': 'Saelyth', 'invokerid': '18472', 'msg': 'test message', 'invokeruid': 'myuniqueid'}]
<class 'list'>
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

**What is the problem?**
I want to be able to use the items in the response separately. As example I'd like to print only the invokername or only the msg. I believe the code needed would be `event.parsed['msg']` but it's giving me troubles trying to make it since it doesn't appear to be a dict at all.

How can i use the items in the list in the desired way?

Expected answer: print(Only 1 item information)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have a list object with *one* dictionary in it. You can access the dictionary by first indexing the list, then the contained dictionary:

```
print event.parsed[0]['msg']
```

Comment: ...This never happened! I can't believe i didn't tried that earlier. Thank you for the answer, will accept it in 6 minutes :P